# Manually creating FeedItem to post in Chatter, not appearing in Chatter feed

Tags: apex, chatter

In our Salesforce instance, when viewing an Account (we use Person Accounts), the Chatter feed shows new record creations related to this account.

We have this set up for Tasks, where Tasks have "Enable Feed Tracking" set, so that when a new Task is created with the WhatId set to a Person Account, a new Chatter entry appears linking to the Task.

I'm trying to programmatically create a Chatter post in an Apex trigger. I'm basically doing:

```
    FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
    item.ParentId = task.Id;
    item.Type = 'CreateRecordEvent';
    insert item;
```

In this example `task` is a Task related to the Account. This code executes, however the Chatter post is not visible on the Account's chatter feed. I also do not see the chatter entry if the ParentId is set to the Account Id.

How can I manually create a chatter entry for a record being created related to an account? I see the [ConnectApi method #postFeedElement()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element.htm), however I don't know what the "communityId" would be in this case as I'm just trying to add a chatter entry for a (Person) Account.

Comment: I think there are few other fields you should pass in your code. Where's the body, what's the visibility, etc???

Comment: Visibility is set by default and body is not required for some post types https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm

Comment: The link you referred clearly says body is required. It is optional only for content type for which an attachments is a required option. For the visibility part, you are right it is set by default.

Comment: The body is not required, as the event salesforce creates by default has a type of "CreateRecordEvent" and a null body. The docs are either misleading or incorrect